# Controlling transitions when Flex mobile changes between portrait and landscape

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

I'm developing a mobile application in Flex 4.6, and I have the autoOrient property set to true so that Flex takes care of changing between portrait and landscape mode when the phone is rotated. This works, but...

The transition between portrait and landscape consists of the application rotating from one position to the other and it doesn't look good at all. I would like to have Flex just cut or fade between the two screen orientations *without* rotating, but I can't find where I could control this.

My application is based on a ViewNavigatorApplication if that helps with the answer.

I guess what I'm looking for is something like the sort of control you can have when changing between views with something like:

navigator.defaultPushTransition = new FlipViewTransition();

but to do with portrait/landscape transitions instead.

Comment: I think the rotation effect is handled by iOS. In that case, you can't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the orientation change event (`StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE`) and set a transition to your desired container.

Comment: Thanks - I'm already listening to ORIENTATION_CHANGE - but what transition can I set - and on what container - to affect the portrait/landscape change - that's what I haven't been able to work out.

Comment: The container would be the container you like to animate, in case you wanna animate the whole application, you would use the `Application` container. For detailed information about animations/effects, see for example this: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_effects_pt1.html

Comment: Ok - thanks. I was really hoping to avoid having to roll my own. Gotta say I'm finding Flex Mobile a bit of a disappointment so far - both the scaling and the transitions (rotation and transitions between views) have been a bit rubbish, and have resulted in me writing code of my own. No complaints about AS3 and the Flash libraries, but the next level of abstraction up hasn't done it for me.